# How to combine array1 from matching id's of array2 using foreach reference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. `array1` contains details of users and `array2` has personal details.  How do I merge `array2` into `array1` by using foreach reference?

```
$array1 = [
['id'=> 1,'name'=>'John Sena', 'lastname'=>'Jonn'],
['id'=> 2,'name'=>'Rock', 'lastname'=>'Rock Sena']
];

$array2 = [
['id'=>1, 'company'=>'Warner Brother'], ['id'=>2, 'company'=>'Metro'],['id'=>'1', 'Address'=>'USA']
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and in the second [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) use pass by reference for `&$a1`

```
$array1 = [
    ['id'=> 1,'name'=>'John Sena', 'lastname'=>'Jonn'],
    ['id'=> 2,'name'=>'Rock', 'lastname'=>'Rock Sena']
];

$array2 = [
    ['id'=>1, 'company'=>'Warner Brother'], ['id'=>2, 'company'=>'Metro'],['id'=>'1', 'Address'=>'USA']
];

foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
    foreach ($array1 as &$a1) {
        if ($a2['id'] == $a1['id']) {
            $a1 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
        }
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John Sena
            [lastname] => Jonn
            [company] => Warner Brother
            [Address] => USA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Rock
            [lastname] => Rock Sena
            [company] => Metro
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QsEa8)

Comment: fourth bid, Thanks for solution which i was looking of it. can you pls explain when we should use foreach value reference

Comment: From the documentation of [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference. In this case `$value` will be `&$a1`

Comment: There are examples of this usage in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, is it possible to add comma seperated value if the same mobile and phone number of same id in array2?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you mean in the same array or when merging from array2 to array1? There are no phone or mobile keys in the example data. What you might do is ask a new question where you add your example data and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code instead of writing foreach's:

```
$res = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$res = array_reduce($res, function($acc, $item) {
    $acc[$item['id']] = isset($acc[$item['id']]) ? 
                        array_merge($acc[$item['id']], $item) :
                        $acc[$item['id']] = $item;
    return $acc;
});
```